# chdir to directory with spaces

Tags: linux, unix, find, cd

I am running the following command:

```
cd $(find /tmp/my_temp/ -type d -wholename '/tmp/my_temp/MyNumb-*_WeCo - MX')
```

It returns somethingn like this:

```
/tmp/nolio_temp/MyNumb-15_WeCo - MX
```

When trying to `cd` to this output I cannot because there are spaces.

Is there any way to `cd` to the directory that is returned by `find` even though there are spaces present?

Comment: Quoting is the right thing to do, but if you only want to execute a command in that directory you can also -execdir command. Then you need to match however files inside the dir or expect to be executed in the parent dir.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where that `find` command returns more than one result?

Answer (score 2):

Just quote it and it will work:

```
cd "$()"
```

In your case:

```
cd "$(find /tmp/my_temp/ -type d -wholename '/tmp/my_temp/MyNumb-*_WeCo - MX')"
```

This way you tell `cd` to use as an argument what is within the double quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while avoiding the double quote character? Single quotes dont work

Comment: No. Single quotes won't expand the expression.

Comment: Alternatively you could escape the spaces, but this looks cleaner.

Comment: Only safe if it's guaranteed that only one result will be found.

Comment: @DaxDurax, could you expand on _why_ you want to avoid double quotes? There may be a better way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: This will also fail if `find` returns more than one directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mouthful, but the following is extra paranoid in terms of working correctly in odd corner cases:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' dirname \
  < <(find /tmp/my_temp/ -type d -wholename '/tmp/my_temp/MyNumb-*_WeCo - MX' -print0)
cd "$dirname"
```

This will handle filenames ending in whitespace, filenames containing newlines (including trailing newlines, which `$()` will eat), cases where `find` returns only one result, and other such oddballs.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to [fedorqui’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907812/123109), you wrote that you want to avoid using double-quotes in your command. I’m curious to know why, but you can do it, in `bash` at least, with

```
eval 'cd '$(find /tmp/nolio_temp -type d \
  -wholename '/tmp/nolio_temp/MyNumb-*_WeCo - MX' |
    sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
```

But be very careful of malicious filenames.